# How to sample from a truncated CDF that is a tranformation of a gamma distribution?

Tags: distributions, sampling, matlab, gamma-distribution

I would like to sample from a cumulative distribution function $G$, which is a transformation of a 2-parameter Gamma : $G  = q * F_{\gamma} + (1-q)$
where $F_{\gamma}$ is the Gamma CDF. In my case, it leaded to this kind of figure:

[image]

My $x$ is 0 for the probability from 0 to 0.88. Actually, I don't how to do it properly with this discontinuity at zero.

For the moment, I'm working numerically, meaning not on the equation formulated above. I access the function for different values of x, with a small increment, to create my CDF like in the figure. Then I sample from the vector of cumulative probability (CDF) with a matlab function (datasample).  The question is: how could I include the part from 0 in the 0.88 in that vector? How I choose the increment? Because I could have an infinity of value in that interval and mislead my sampling.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Why the log scale here?Presumably, you just want to plot x from 0 to 20? What is the value of $q$?  OP writes:    `My x is 0 for the probability from 0 to 0.88` /// --> I don't understand. How is your cdf truncated? What is a truncated cdf?

Comment: Yes, you are right for the log scale here, it was necessary for other distributions not show here. Maybe the term truncated is not right, sorry I'm not a statistician but only a user. Actually, my $F_{\gamma}$ cdf is defined by two- piece function: 0 for x from  0 to 1 and gamma distribution for x>1; and then I work with conditional probabilities that's why I have to multiply by q and to add (1-q) to get my "total" CDF, on which I have to do sampling.

Comment: Because your figure vanished, your question is no longer understandable.  Could you repost it on imgurl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some MATLAB code to illustrate combining a point mass at x=0 with probability 0.8, and a gamma distribution above x=0 with parameters 2 and 2. I have a plot of the cdf, the inverse cdf, and the empirical cdf after I sample from it.

```
% Look at the cdf of a mixture of a gamma and point mass distribution
subplot(1,3,1)
x = linspace(0,20)';
y = 0.8 + .2*cdf('gamma',x,2,2);    % gamma distribution above x=0
x = [0;x]; y = [0;y];               % point mass of prob 0.8 at x=0
plot(x,y)
xlim([-.5 20])
title('cdf')

% Look at the inverse cdf
subplot(1,3,2)
p = linspace(.01,.99);
y = zeros(size(p));
y(p<.8) = 0;
y(p>.8) = icdf('gamma',5*(p(p>.8)-.8),2,2);
plot(p,y)
title('inverse cdf')

% Write an inverse cdf and sample from it
f = @(p) (p<.8).*0 + ...
         (p>.8).*icdf('gamma',max(0,5*(p-.8)),2,2)
u = rand(10000,1);
y = f(u);
subplot(1,3,3)
ecdf(y)
title('empirical cdf of sample')
```